# "Invalid thread access" Exception when creating Cloudio wordcloud from Eclipse plugin

Tags: multithreading, exception, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

I'm trying to create wordclouds in my Eclipse plugin. I decided to use Cloudio and to start with a small test using [this](http://git.eclipse.org/c/gef/org.eclipse.gef4.git/tree/org.eclipse.gef4.cloudio.examples.ui/src/org/eclipse/gef4/cloudio/examples/snippets/TagCloudSnippet.java).

When I run this class as a Java application (not as a plugin), it works like a charm.

But when I call the method from within another plugin, I get the following error: (I think it's worthwhile to mention that all other functionalities from the package in which I added the wordcloud-class are working fine, so it's most likely not some dependecy-issue I guess)

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:68)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:799)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:675)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$7(HandledContributionItem.java:659)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:592)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)

Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4377)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDisplay(Display.java:775)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:837)
        at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:480)
        at de.uni_bremen.aide.wordcloud.WordCloud.main(WordCloud.java:69)
        at de.uni_bremen.aide.tfidf.TfIdf.writeWeightsToFile(TfIdf.java:73)
        at de.uni_bremen.aide.clones.SummariesGeneratorHandler.execute(SummariesGeneratorHandler.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
        ... 38 more
```

Maybe someone already had such an issue and could tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Looks like `de.uni_bremen.aide.wordcloud.WordCloud.main` is trying to create a new `Display` object when one already exists. SWT does not allow this.

Comment: Hey Greg, thank you, this was exactly the issue. I replaced it with Display.getCurrent() and it works like a charm.